# Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a scatter plot, but keep getting the error "Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data." I have looked at other questions pertaining to this, but seem unable to figure out how to apply them here. The issue pertains specifically to trying to add a second layer. The following code works fine:

```
scatter1 <- ggplot(ratios3, aes(ratios3$`CPI-U 2015 (Official)`, 
        ratios3$`PCE1 2015`)) + 
    geom_point(shape=1) +
    theme_bw()
scatter1 + 
    labs(title="Relationship Between CPI RI and PCE RI \n(Unadjusted)", 
        x = "CPI RI", y = "Unadj. PCE RI") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family="Times")) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(family = "Times"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Times", face = "plain", size = 
        12), axis.title.y = element_text(family = "Times", face = "bold", 
        size = 12)) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black")) +
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, .05, .1, .15, .2, .25)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, .05, .1, .15, .2, .25)) +
    annotate(geom="text", x=.195, y=.120, label="Owners' Equivalent Rent", 
        size=3, family="Times") +
    annotate(geom="text", x=.077, y=.040, label="Rent", size=3, 
        family="Times") +
    annotate(geom="text", x=.022, y=.100, label="Hospital Services", size=3, 
        family="Times") +
    annotate(geom="text", x=.029, y=.048, label="Physicians' Services", 
        size=3, family="Times") +
    annotate(geom="text", x=.025, y=.032, label="Prescription Drugs", 
        size=3, family="Times")
```

What I would like to do is highlight the outliers in the data frame. While there seem to be other ways to color certain points than the code below, this seemed the cleanest and simplest; furthermore, I tried multiple other options to no avail as well. Based on recommendations, this is what I added (after creating data frame "outliers"):

```
geom_point(data = outliers, colour = "red", shape=1) +
```

Doing this yielded the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): x, y
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: you should try to taking out the `ratios3$` in your first aesthetic - although I don't know if you'll still be able to backtick-protect your variable names with spaces in them ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben's comment got me thinking about variable names, and I realized there were no specified variables in outliers (the original data frame, ratios3, and outliers both have many variables). I simply needed to specify the same variables:

```
  geom_point(data = outliers, aes(`CPI-U 2015 (Official)`, `PCE1 2015`), 
      colour = "red", shape=1) +
```